# Cmake and coding style for common config code

Tags: c++, coding-style, cmake, configuration-files

following the structure of my project:

```
/myproject
  CMakeLists.txt (containing "add_subdirectory" and "include_directories" ..)
  /src
    /lib1
      CMakeLists.txt (containing "add_library(lib1 .. )" )
      ..
    /lib2
      idem as lib1 ..
  /mains
    /common
      =>config.cpp<=
      =>gui.cpp<=
    /main1
      CMakeLists.txt
      main1.cpp
    /main2
      CMakeLists.txt
      main2.cpp
  /data
    /images_and_different_stuff
  /conf
    params.cfg
  /bin
     (output executables)
  /release
     (cmake build_files)
```

My question is about the linking of the configuration classes I placed in `/common`. These classes read the CLI or the configuration file `params.cfg` and initialize mains objects that are present in both main1.cpp and main2.cpp and main3.cpp ... (one config file for all exes)
For now I have in my `/main1's CMakeLists.txt`: `set(main1_source main1.cpp ../common/config.cpp ..)`. So the common code is recompile for each exe. What is the best way to do this ? Make a static lib from common files ?

Comment: I would do a static library to be linked by both applications, but if you will publish the applications and make them installable then maybe it would be better to make the common library dynamic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the best way to do this ? Make a static lib from common files ?

Exactly.  Or use a shared library if you want to cut down your total install size.